# How pass BeanShell param from one Thread Group to a Counter in another Thread Group

Tags: multithreading, variables, properties, jmeter, beanshell

I need to pass a value from one Thread Group to another Thread Group, in particular I have to pass a value from BeanShell sampler to Counter. This is my BeanShell code:

```
Counter.Calendar c = 
Calendar.getInstance();
long now = c.getTimeInMillis();
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
long passed = (now - c.getTimeInMillis())/1000;
vars.putObject("startTime",passed);
${__setProperty("start",vars.getObject("startTime"))};
```

and I have to use *passed* value into Counter as Start value.I set ${__P("start")} or ${__property("start")} but neither of the two worked.
I tried to use this method also into BeanShell Sample of another thread group, but i had error. In the same Beanshell it works and sets variable.
How can I use properties or other way to pass this value?
thanks

PS: If I ${__setProperty("start",123)}; it works (other thread receives 123), else it doesn't see the variable. Also if I put beanshell sapler in the same thread have a problem: given that Counter is processed before sampler, the counter value isn't updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties can only be strings. Try something like this:

`props.put("start", Long.toString(passed));`

On the receiving side you will have to convert back to a long.

For sharing data that is not a string, you can use the BeanShell shared namespace, `bsh.shared`.
See http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html

Comment: thanks, I try with convertions. For bsh.shared can't use  it because I Must use variable into Counter and not into Beanshell